# NPM: Can't make the Mustache.js bundle to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, webpack

I am bundling 6 different modules together in Webpack. One of then is [Mustache.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache).

The Mustache templates live inside the HTML page. They are not in a separate file. Now when I load my page ... I get this error ...[image]

This is my **app.js** file

```
require('mustache');
require("./js/modules.js");
require("./js/custom.js");
require('owl.carousel');
require('bootstrap');
require("expose-loader?$!jquery");
```

I have tried changing the order, but nothing is working.

The 'modules.js' file has a dependency on 'mustache'. So I went into the modules.js file and added `require('mustache');` at the top in that file, but nothing changed. Do I need to add any additional configuration to my webpack.config.js file ?

If I take the Mustache.js modules out of the bundle and load it normally on the html page like `<script src="js/mustache.js"></script>` then everything works fine.

Can someone please advise how can I include this module in the bundle ? Already wasted so many hours trying to make this work, but to no avail. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's working when not bundled because you reference the script directly in the DOM and `Mustache` is added to the global scope, in this case window.Mustache.

In your app.js or any other 'bundled' script that is referencing Mustache you'll need to require and assign to a variable:

`var Mustache = require('mustache');`

Comment: Thanks @DanD Adding this `var Mustache = require('mustache');` (to the modules.js file which require Mustache) worked .... I though just using `require('mustache');` should work, but that's wan't the case. Anyway, many thanks mate, all good now.